# Timeouts while deploying application to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu-11.04

I have a problem while deploying application to GAE. I use ubuntu. When I type command to update application this error occurs:

```
2011-07-22 20:13:28,598 ERROR appcfg.py:2064 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2005, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1674, in Begin
    self.Send('/api/appversion/create', payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1632, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 365, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1193, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 367, in do_open
    raise url_error
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 76, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "./google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 72, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3708, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3699, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2345, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3484, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2745, in Update
    app_summary = self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2734, in UpdateVersion
    lambda path: self.opener(os.path.join(basepath, path), 'rb'))
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2005, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1674, in Begin
    self.Send('/api/appversion/create', payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1632, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 365, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1193, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/home/grzegorz/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 367, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

I tried to figure out why this happens, especially that it didn't happen to me before.
Anything that I've done about it just didn't work. What's weird is that if I keep trying, then after about 20-30 attemps - it just magically deploys..

In my opinion there might be some Wifi problems. For example when I start xChat - it can't connect to server. I think that this problems might be connected.

Nevertheless I can't figure out anything, so I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: I have yet to have any problems with Python 2.7, so long as I write code that is valid in Python 2.5.

Comment: If you know you have problems with other programs such as xChat, then this is not a programming problem and this is the wrong site. Try superuser.

Comment: Does this problem still exist? If you connect via an ethernet cable are you able to deploy?

Comment: The problem still exist in that laptop, but as it turned out there was a big problem with drivers to my network card. Since then I bought a new laptop so it's outdated.